# Performance of rails app goes down due to log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a rails app, where the speed of the application reduces significantly as the size of the log file increases. I need to deleted my log file(backup) frequently to prevent this. What is the best practice to avoid this.

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a production environment, the ideal is to set `logrotate` rules for those logs (preferably daily).

We do it and never had performance issues due to logs.

[Here's a brief article on how to use it.](http://linuxers.org/howto/howto-use-logrotate-manage-log-files)